# How to unbind jquery.scrollTo plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, scrollto, unbind

I use the jquery scrollto plugin on this page : http://tinyurl.com/3l49ccu)

When i resize the window, the scroll is not working anymore because the "offset" setting changed. I would like to redefine this setting on resize.

The author of the plugin explain "how to unbind" in the comments of this page : http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/03/jqueryserialscroll-110-released.html

but i couldn't make it work.

i tried this :

```
    $(window).bind("resize", function(){
    $('#sideshow').unbind('.serialScroll');
    }
```

thanks

---

still investigating… 
i asked about this problem here : 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-reset-serialscroll-settings-on-window-resize

Answer (score 0):

do in this way..remove `.`

```
 $(window).bind("resize", function(){
    $('#sideshow').unbind('serialScroll');
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I put the code, but the problem is still here. after resize, do i have to do something else to redefine the "offset" value ?

Answer (score 0):

The dot is correct, because `unbind('.serialScroll')`removes all name spaced events. Still, I could not get around the problem. One thing I noticed is, that the line `$("#slideshow p").css("width", (parseInt(slideshowWidth)-2) + "px");`causes the width of the p expand on resize.

Another thing I noticed was that the plugin uses the scrollLeft property of the #slideshow to adjust the position of the slideshow. I tried the following steps but did not succeed, while editing in browser. Maybe you have more luck when editing your local files:

1. unbind all serialscroll events with `$('#sideshow').unbind('.serialScroll');`
2. initialize serialscroll like you do at pageload
3. set the scrollLeft property on #slideshow back to where it was

My main problem was that the slideshow animated to the first picture. Setting the scrollLeft property was useless, because it was instantly overriden by the animation. I was not able to figure out how to stop the animation in no time, so I leave this to you.

Good luck

Comment: thank you. I tried what you suggest here : http://goo.gl/ZP6n4 (line 57-61). no success yet.

Comment: i fixed the #slideshow p wich was expanding on resize. it didn't fix the problem neither… still searching